# vue.js - bind sass styling from one component to another

Tags: javascript, css, sass, vue.js

this question is about vue.js, that operates on a boilerplate that using webpack configuration.

i need to dynamically pass sass variables from component `father` to component `son` (for the simplicity of naming).

on component `father` i have access to `$color` variable from the style tag.
and i'm calling to `son` component using this html template:

```
// father component
    <template>
        <son></son>
    </template>
    <style lang='sass' scoped>
        @import 'assets/sass/color';
    </style>
```

imported sass variable, `$color` need to come from `father` and change the background of `son`

let's say son is just a simple div.

```
// son component
    <template>
        <div></div>
    </template>

    <style lang=sass scoped>
        div {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
```

what's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

you can import sass and use binding like,

```
<p v-bind:style="[baseStyles, overrideStyles]">
baseStyles and overrideStyles
</p>
```

**EDIT**

or you can do something like

```
<template>
    <div v-bind:class="$style.my_component">Hello</div>
</template>
<style module>
    .my_component {
        color: purple; // still the best color ever
    }
</style>
```

Comment: didn't really understand ... where those values inside the array are declared as sass values?

Comment: you can import in style tag, and then you can access your classed via `$style.classname` var, check the  **edit** and use class binding

Answer (score 0):

Besides of your scoped stylings you could also use global ones in the same component which would get exposed to the child component. Just add a new style tag to your component, without using the `scoped` key.

Your component could look somehow like that.

```
<style>
/* global styles */
</style>

<style scoped>
/* local styles */
</style>
```

[Source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/blob/master/docs/en/features/scoped-css.md)